# Type traits and unevaluated context

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, type-traits

cppreference.com says about [`is_assignable<T,U>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable) type-trait that:

> If the expression `std::declval<T>() = std::declval<U>()` is well-formed in unevaluated context, provides the member constant value equal true. For any other type, value is false. The types T and U must be complete object types, cv void or arrays of unknown bound. Access checks are performed as if from a context unrelated to either type.

But code:

```
template< std::size_t ...indices, std::size_t ...counter >
auto
invert_indices(std::index_sequence< counter... >)
{
    constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(counter);
    constexpr std::size_t inverted[size]{indices...};
    return std::index_sequence< inverted[size - 1 - counter]... >{};
}

template< std::size_t ...indices >
auto
invert_indices()
{
    return invert_indices< indices... >(std::make_index_sequence< sizeof...(indices) >{});
}

template< std::size_t ...indices >
using make_inverted_indices_t = decltype(invert_indices< indices... >());

using L = make_inverted_indices_t< 10, 20, 30 >;
using R = std::index_sequence< 30, 20, 10 >;
static_assert(std::is_same< L, R >{});
static_assert(std::is_assignable< make_inverted_indices_t< 10, 20, 30 > &, R >{});
static_assert(!std::is_assignable< make_inverted_indices_t< 10, 20, 30 > &, int >{});
```

work, in spite of functions `invert_indices` are not `constexpr` and have result type `auto`.

For context to be unevaluated is it still permittable to look into function bodies during `decltype` working?

Answer (score 2):

`invert_indices< indices... >()` is not evaluated, but its return type is known. It requires to look at body to know its type because of the `auto` return type.

so `make_inverted_indices_t< 10, 20, 30 >` is `std::index_sequence< 30, 20, 10 >` which is a complete object type.

Answer (score 2):

The types produced are not part of `is_assignable`.  `T` and `U` are produced completely independently of what the semantics of `is_assignable` are.

The docs around `is_assignable` describe what it does to the types.  But `invert_indexes` is evaluated by `make_inverted_indexes_t`, not by `is_assignable`.  And `make_inverted_indexes_t` clearly evaluates the body of `invert_indexes`.

All of this happens before `is_assignable` is passed the types.

If we instead look at things that happen after `is_assignable` is passed the types, here I create a toy type:

```
template<size_t N>
struct foo {
  template<std::size_t K>
  decltype(auto) operator=(foo<K> const& in){
    static_assert( (K<N) );
    return in;
  }
};
```

which in the immediate context looks like it can be assigned to-from every other `foo`, and

```
template<size_t N>
struct foo {
  template<std::size_t K, class=std::enable_if_t<(K<N)>>
  decltype(auto) operator=(foo<K> const& in){
    static_assert( (K<N) );
    return in;
  }
};
```

which adds a SFINAE guard.  If we run these tests:

```
using L = foo<10>;
using R = foo<11>;
static_assert(!std::is_same< L, R >{});
static_assert(!std::is_assignable< L &, R >{});
static_assert(std::is_assignable< R &, L >{});
static_assert(!std::is_assignable< L &, std::string >{});
```

in the first case, we get hard errors as the body of `operator=` is evaluated.  In the second case, the SFINAE guard kicks in, and everything passes.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b6516c226babb46).

So what goes on is that even in the unevaluated context, the bodies of functions are evaluated if their return type is `auto`, at least in practice.